# HTML not linking to CSS file

Tags: html, css

TL;DR: My HTML isn't linking to a stylesheet.

Right off the bat, sorry for so much code.
I have checked other questions, but none had such a strange circumstance as I did.

I have a file, `loggedIn.html`:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Logged in!</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="cgi-bin/style.css">
        </head>

        <body>
                You are now logged in!
                <a href="cgi-bin/logout.php">Logout</a>
        </body>
</html>
```

Which uses the stylesheet `style.css`:

```
body { font-family: Georgia, Goudy, Sabon, serif; }
```

Along with `loggedIn.html`, `index.html` uses `style.css`:

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Welcome!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cgi-bin/style.css">
</head>

<body>
        <h2>Welcome to That Guy's Fileshare Server!</h2>
        <hr/>
        Please log in.
        <br/>

        <form action="cgi-bin/login.php" method="POST">
                <p>
                <table border="0">
                                <tr>
                                        <td> <label for="username">Username: </label> </td>
                                        <td> <input type="text" name="username"/> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td> <label for="password">Password: </label> </td>
                                        <td> <input type="password" name="password"/> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td> <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                </p>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <a href="register.html">Register</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="note.html">Contact information</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Since both `loggedIn.html` and `index.html` use the same stylesheet, shouldn't they both be rendered in Georgia, Goudy, Sabon, or a serif font? Apparently not. The file structure is:

```
┌ index.html
├ loggedIn.html
└ cgi-bin/
   └─────────── style.css
```

The file structure shouldn't be a problem either, since both `.html` files are in the same directory and use `href="cgi-bin/style.css"`. I've never had a problem like this before. Very strange!

Comment: maybe a caching issue ... did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: Apart from a seemingly rhetorical question about which font should be used, you haven't actually explained what the problem is. I'd also suggest that `cgi-bin` isn't the place to keep your files.

Comment: @MartinTurjak Just cleared my cache and reloaded. Not a caching issue, it's most likely server-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

forgot your type.
Also check the location of the css file.
I believe leaving out the type will cause problems.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='cgi-bin/style.css'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do

```
<style type="text/css"> @import "cgi-bin/style.css"; </style>
```